# modify path globally

Tags: shell, arch-linux, standard, path

Is there a standard for `$PATH` and the order of things that are supposed to be in there? out of the box Arch Linux doesn't have `/usr/local/bin` in the `$PATH`. I want to add it but I'm not sure if there's a predefined pecking order for system paths.

Also where is the right place to do this? for right now I modified `/etc/profile` but I'm not sure that's the right place in Arch for user modifications. Anyone know if there's a better place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arch is a minimalistic linux distribution, so normally there are no other special configuration files which are getting included in some strange placces, modified by system configuration wizards.

`/etc/profile` is the right place to do this for a system wide configuration.

> This file is intended to be used for
>   ALL common Bourne-compatible shells.
>   Shell specifics should be handled in
>   /etc/profile.$SHELL where $SHELL is
>   the name of the binary being run
>   (discounting symlinks)

[It is also mentioned in the official FAQ for reloading if your shell can't find a newly installed binary](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FAQ#Q.29_I_just_installed_Package_X._How_do_I_start_it.3F)

Comment: ok. I was debating on whether I should make the change in `/etc/profile.d/somefile` or something. Which would mean less maintenance if arch update `/etc/profile` but if there's an order specified in LSB for PATH it might not conform.

Answer (score 4):

By "globally", do you mean for all users? I put my path modifications in `~/.profile`, as it affects X applications as well. If you want it in the system profile it's probably best to modify `/etc/profile`

Comment: yes by globally I meant all users.